# Generate multiple scriptblock through the pipeline in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Basically I want to make the following concise using the pipeline:

`{Remove-Job 27}, {Remove-Job 29} | % { Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $_; };`

To something like (conceptually)

`@(27, 29) | % {Remove-Job $_;} | % { Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $_; };`

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example isn't quite right, because you have to emit a `ScriptBlock` in order to call `Invoke-Command` on it. Therefore, rather than actually **calling** `Remove-Job` on the local machine, you'd want to pass it as a `ScriptBlock` to the remote computer. Here is the most concise way I can think of at the moment, to achieve what you're after:

```
27, 29 | % { Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Remove-Job -Id $args[0]; } -ArgumentList $_; };
```

Even though you didn't explicitly come out and display the code, it's obvious that you are pre-creating the PowerShell Session (aka. `PSSession`) object, prior to calling `Invoke-Command`. You can also simplify things by not pre-creating the `PSSession`, and simply using `Invoke-Command` with the `-ComputerName` parameter. Here is an example:

```
$ComputerList = @('server01.contoso.com', 'server02.contoso.com', 'server03.contoso.com');
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerList -ScriptBlock { Remove-Job -Id $args[0]; } -ArgumentList 27,29;
```

**Note**: I also moved the `Job` IDs directly into `-ArgumentList`, rather than piping them in. I generally try to avoid using the PowerShell pipeline, unless it really makes sense (eg. taking advantage of `Where-Object`, `Get-Member`, or `Select-Object`). Everyone has a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually tried this previously, but I've got the following error: ``Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Id'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Job], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Remov
   eJobCommand
    + PSComputerName        : xxx.xx...``

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test my code before I posted it :) I noticed what I did wrong, though. Since the `ScriptBlock` is a separate scope, we have to pass the `Job ID` in via the `-ArgumentList` parameter on `Invoke-Command`, and then reference it via `$args[0]`. I updated the code appropriately (after testing this time) :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I will take a look at how `-ArgumentList` works.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason this wouldn't work?

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { 27,29 |% {Remove-Job -Id $_ } }
```

Comment: Good answer - it depends on where the `Job` IDs are coming from, though. If he somehow wanted to pass them from the local system, he'd need to use `-ArgumentList`, as in my answer.

Comment: You could use [scriptblock]::create if they're arbitrary IDs.  It would simplify the scripting if the jobs were named when they were created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want the job ID's to be the leftmost thing of the command since that is the only part I'm editing for different job ID's. Having it there makes editing easier - otherwise I have to press many arrow keys :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use variable expansion, and the `Create()` method on the `ScriptBlock` type.

```
27, 29 | % { Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $([ScriptBlock]::Create("Remove-Job -Id $_")) };
```

I'm not sure that is any more concise than Trevor's approach.

Answer (score 0):

The `Id` parameter of the `Remove-Job` cmdlet accepts an array of ID's so you could speicfy them like so:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Remove-Job -Id 27,29 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want the job ID's to be the leftmost thing of the command since that is the only part I'm editing for different job ID's. Having it there makes editing easier - otherwise I have to press many arrow keys :)